# (x,y) pair for max z value in list

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list of lists such as:

```
nodes =[[nodeID,x,y,z],....]
```

I want to find:

```
xi,yi for zi=zmax given zmax= max z for same x,y
```

and store the `(xi,yi,zi)` in another list.

I can do this using:

```
nodes=[[literal_eval(x) for x in item] for item in nodes]
maxz_levels=[]
for i,row in enumerate(nodes):
    fe=0
    maxz=0
    nodeID,x,y,z=row
    for j,line in enumerate(nodes):
        nodeID2,x2,y2,z2=line
        if x==x2 and y==y2 and z2>maxz:
            maxz=z2
    if len(maxz_levels)==0:
        maxz_levels.append([x, y, maxz])
    else:
        for row2 in maxz_levels:
            if row2[0]==x and row2[1]==y:
                fe=1
        if fe==0:
            maxz_levels.append([x, y, maxz])
```

but it takes ages... so I thought of using a dictionary but I'm not finding an easy way to do what I want. My code is:

```
dic1=defaultdict(list)             
for nodeID,x,y,z in nodes:
    dic1[(x,y)].append((nodeID,z))
for key in dic1:
    dic1[key].sort( key=lambda x:float(x[1]) )
for j,row in enumerate(nodes):
    nodeID,x,y,z=row
    z_levels=[item[1] for item in dic1[(x,y)]]
    #How to find easily and quickly the max of z_levels and the associated (x,y) coordinates?
```

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT:
example:

```
nodes = [['1','1','1','2'],['2','1','1','3'],['3','0','0','5'],['4','0','0','4'],['5','1','2','4'],['6','0','0','40'],['7','0','10','4'],['8','10','0','4'],['9','0','0','4'],['10','2','1','4']]
```

I want to find:

```
maxz_levels = [[1, 1, 3], [0, 0, 40], [1, 2, 4], [0, 10, 4], [10, 0, 4], [2, 1, 4]]
```

Comment: You should init `maxz` within the first loop I think. It won't answer your problem but I'm not sure your current solution works.

Comment: Yes you are right! But in my case it works because maxz is always the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you items are ordered by your X and Y, then:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

nodes = [['1','1','1','2'],['2','1','1','3'],['3','0','0','5'],['4','0','0','4']]    
result = [max(g, key=itemgetter(3))[1:] for k, g in groupby(nodes, itemgetter(1, 2))]
# [['1', '1', '3'], ['0', '0', '5']]
```

Otherwise, you can provide `sorted(nodes, key=itemgetter(1, 2))` instead of `nodes` to `groupby`.

Comment: If they aren't grouped it does not work. If they are it works. My question now is: how to group this list: `nodes = [['1','1','1','2'],['2','1','1','3'],['3','0','0','5'],['4','0','0','4'],['5','1','2','4'],
['6','0','0','40'],['7','0','10','4'],['8','10','0','4'],['9','0','0','4'],['10','2','1','4']]`

Answer (score 1):

<del>You could use the `max` function with a key:


`maxz = max(list_, key=lambda x: x[3])`


This will assign `maxz` to the item of the list `list_` with the maximum value with index 3 (z value). You can then extract the `xi` and `yi` values:


    `xi, yi = (maxz[1], maxz[2])`</del>

---

<del>If you want to sort your `nodes` list by z, you could use the `sorted` function together with a `key`:


    `maxz_levels = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x[3], reverse=True)`

and then remove the first item.</del>

---

Alright, I think I finally got your question. So here's a functional attempt:

```
maxz_levels = []
for i in set([(i[1], i[2]) for i in nodes]):
    m = sorted(filter(lambda x: x[1] == i[0] and x[2] == i[1], nodes))[-1]
    maxz_levels.append((m[1], m[2], m[3]))
```

Explanation:

- The `for` loop loops through a list of all `(x, y)` combinations in `nodes`
- The first line in the loop sorts a list of all items in `nodes` with the current `(x, y)` values by their `z` value and takes the last one (the one with the biggest `z` value).
- The second line in the loop then adds this node to the list of maximum nodes.

Comment: That will give you an absolute maximum. The result should be a list of (x, y, z) grouped by (x, y).

Comment: I would need to build `list_` as a list with same `x,y` coordinates. I think my `z_levels` list can be used. I'll try.

Comment: That will not do what I want. If `nodes =[['1','1','1','2'],['2','1','1','3'],['3','0','0','1'],['4','0','0','4']]` then I get `[['4', '0', '0', '4'], ['2', '1', '1', '3'], ['1', '1', '1', '2'], ['3', '0', '0', '1']]` but I want `[['0', '0', '4'], ['1', '1', '3']]`...

Comment: @jpcgandre: So you only want the first 2 items? Then just add `maxz_levels = maxz_levels[:2]`

Comment: @jazzpi: No, I want the all `(x,y,z)` in which `z` is the maximum `z` for the same `(x,y)` values.

Comment: @jpcgandre: I don't think I can follow you. (0, 0) isn't the same as (1, 1).

Comment: Ok, so for the same (x,y) I want to find the maximum z... so in my example I have two different (x,y): (0,0) and (1,1) and for each I find the max z: 4 and 3.

Comment: For example, using the new example I get this wrong result: `[(1, 2, 4), (0, 0, 4), (2, 1, 4), (0, 10, 4), (10, 0, 4), (1, 1, 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


nodes = [['1','1','1','2'],['2','1','1','3'],['3','0','0','5'],['4','0','0','4']]

d = {}

for z in nodes:
    x = (z[1], z[2])
    if x not in d:
        d[x] = z[3]
    elif d[x] < z[3]:
        d[x] = z[3]

output = []
for x in d:
    output.append(x+(d[x],))
print(output)
```

Output:

```
[('0', '0', '5'), ('1', '1', '3')]
```

Comment: @jpcgandre thanks for pointing out the mistake. Have modified the code.